# PHP code explorer - showing classes and functions separately

Tags: php

I wonder if it's possible to view a PHP code source in a way that https://j11y.io/jquery/ shows a JQ code. Of course I mean reading code from a given file, not from websites code.

I'm **not** looking for programs like the PHPdocumentor.

Thank you in advance for any reasonable reply.

P.S. For perfectionists - I'm searching for a nice website or software (and I would prefer that option, so that I can be quite sure about the security), which will give me such a useful ability. I'm disturbed after using CTRL-F all the time ;)

Comment: Use a proper IDE. Most will have an indexed view of all functions and classes in a file, and all properties and methods in a class (some include inherited properties/methods) that you can click to jump to the definition, or you can CTRL+click on a function to jump to the definition.

Comment: I was looking for notepad++ plug-in, but I (literally) find nothing interesting. Could you @rickdenhaan point any IDE, with that option, for php editing on Windows7, please?

Comment: I'm personally a big fan of the JetBrains-suite of editors, so I'd suggest PhpStorm. Adobe's DreamWeaver is pretty good as well. Those are not free though, so if you're looking for something that's free, Eclipse with PDT is pretty good these days. NetBeans used to be OK, but I haven't tried it in years. For a more lightweight IDE, I think Sublime Text also offers these features and is more similar to Notepad++.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Using CTRL-F on PHP code for 2 years is quite inconvenient.

However, I think this question is not yet answered. Such tool, independent from IDE, should be great for understanding someone's code.